# Running a .class java file from cmd. Issue

Tags: java

class file from cmd with the following command and i get the output:

[image]

The error is: "Error: Could not find or load main class CustomerManager.class"

Any idea how i could resolve this issue ?

Comment: not to be weird or anything but why are questions like this answered if one google could show the solution? I mean this just shows NO research effort whatsoever

Comment: Next time, at least provide the error as plain text, so other's with the same problem can search for it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just type in cmd `java CustomerManager` , no need to add `.class`

Comment: It's not no need to add .class, it would be wrong to add .class.

Answer (score 11):

`java CustomerManager`

Without the `.class` extension.

Answer (score 2):

In `java` command `.` character is shows a `/` character and use for path of target class.
For solve your problem, execute your command without `.class` and extension as following:

`java CustomerManager`

(You can found by a little searching in web, very pages that explain it.)

Answer (score 2):

Inside your code , keep your class as Public and then execute

```
java CustomerManager
```

Also cross check in your IDE if there aren't any spaces before or after the class .

Hope this helps .